# Inserting Multiple Rows with Special Formatting

Tags: vba, excel

All,
I am trying to use the code below to insert cells with special formatting (all thin borders and all thick borders around). I have setup a prompt dialog box and then I want all number n rows added to have the format. I am very new to using macros and this could go a long way in helping me out!

```
Sub insertMultipleRows()

Dim iCountRows As Integer

iCountRows = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many rows do you want to add? Starting with row " _
    & ActiveCell.Row & "?", Type:=1)

'Error Handling
If iCountRows <= 0 Then End

If ActiveCell.Row < 9 Then
    MsgBox "You Cannot Insert Rows Before Line 9, Dummy!"
Else
    'Based on number of rows specified, inser these rows
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row & ":" & ActiveCell.Row + iCountRows - 1).Insert shift:=xlDown

    'Formatting
    With ActiveCell.Columns("A:AG").Select
        Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

        ActiveCell.Columns("A:AG").Select
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium

        ActiveCell.Columns("A:AG").Select
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium

        ActiveCell.Columns("A:AG").Select
        Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is working/not working with the code above?

Comment: The formatting is not correct when it inserts the cells. It will only format the first line of the code. I need it to format every single line that it inserts with the thin all around borders and the medium allaround borders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the `Row` number of `ActiveCell.Row` in a variable, since it will change later once you add more `Rows` in your worksheet.

Also, you should avoid using `Select` , instead of using `With ActiveCell.Columns("A:AG").Select` and later also use `Selection`, use something like:

```
With Range(Cells(StartRow + 1, "A"), Cells(StartRow + iCountRows, "AG"))
```

You are after something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub insertMultipleRows()

Dim iCountRows As Long
Dim StartRow As Long

' save the row in a variable
StartRow = ActiveCell.Row

iCountRows = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="How many rows do you want to add? Starting with row " _
    & StartRow & "?", Type:=1)

'Error Handling
If iCountRows <= 0 Then End

If StartRow < 9 Then
    MsgBox "You Cannot Insert Rows Before Line 9, Dummy!"
Else
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' speed up the code's run-time

    'Based on number of rows specified, inser these rows
    Rows(StartRow + 1 & ":" & StartRow + iCountRows).Insert shift:=xlDown

    'Formatting
    With Range(Cells(StartRow + 1, "A"), Cells(StartRow + iCountRows, "AG"))
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin

        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
        .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
        .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlMedium

        ' added these 2 lines
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlMedium
        .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlMedium
    End With
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Shai, I am getting an error at the Rows(StartRow+ .. line in the code?

Comment: Sorry, user error on the error earlier (another macro had protected my spreadsheet and I forgot it. The code looks great!    However, I need the medium borders to be between (top and bottom) every cell added; not just around the n-number of cells added.